# Jenkins controller vs agent capacity planning

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

### Background

Can anyone provide some insight into exactly what the responsibilities of a Jenkins controller is with regards to capacity planning.

I have a single controller and agent set up currently where the controller is a much less powerful EC2 `t2.micro` but the agent is a `t2.medium`.

Every now and then the controller dies and there are errors relating to out of memory errors and unable to allocate memory on checking out a project. Jenkins has been configured with `-Xmx768m`.

I have verified that the build is tied to the ageny node and not the controller. The controller has 0 executors configured and the job shows as running on the agent (1 executor).

### Example Error

This is one such example

```
 ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/xyz.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:825)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1092)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:113)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:130)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.SCMBinder.create(SCMBinder.java:120)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:262)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/xyz.git +refs/pull/16/head:refs/remotes/origin/PR-16 +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/develop" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: error: cannot fork() for fetch-pack: Cannot allocate memory

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1990)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1709)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:400)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:823)
    ... 8 more
```

### My Question

What is the role of the controller in this setup from a resource utilisation perspective? I'd have assumed it would be the agent that is checking out the project and building (not the controller). - hence why I allocate much more resource to the slave in terms of memory, CPU, disk capacity and IOPS.

Aside from centralised plugin configuration I didn't expect the controller to play much of a role beyond starting a job on the agent via SSH (not something I expected to be intensive work from a mem/CPU point of view).

In the short term I plan to upgrade the controller to a more powerful EC2 instance type, however - it'd be good to understand more about what the controller really requires to ensure I'm planning capacity properly and not needlessly provisioning far too much.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error in the build log, and you've scripted your build to run on the slaves, either by requesting a node tag or by reducing the number of the executors on the master to 0, then the checkout *will* happen in the build agent.

If so, then what's running out of memory is not your master, but your slave.

I would try increasing the heap size for the `slave.jar`. How you do this will depend on [how you're firing up the slaves](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Differentwaysofstartingagents).

From [this bit](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service#InstallingJenkinsasaWindowsservice-Changingtheconfigurationofservices) in the Jenkins documentation you'll see it reads:

> The JVM launch parameters of these Windows services are controlled by an XML file `jenkins.xml` and **`jenkins-slave.xml`** respectively. These files can be found in $JENKINS_HOME and in the slave root directory respectively, after you've install them as Windows services. The file format should be self-explanatory. Tweak the arguments **for example to give JVM a bigger memory**.

But if you're firing them up from the command line using `java -jar slave.jar` then here's where you should make use of the `Xmx` parameter. Maybe the box where you're running the agent does have enough memory available, but the Jenkins agent is just not using it.

Also, [here's](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/hardware-recommendations/) a really interesting page in the Jenkins wiki covering how to size both masters and slaves.

Comment: In our case, the job is failing during day when it is performing a git checkout command. However, when it is outside working hours, the job is really stable and works fine. Any idea how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: @tarekahf I would first check which nodes are succeeding and which nodes are failing. Then, try to reduce the number of concurrent jobs on the failing nodes. You may have too many jobs trying to run at the same time. This will make your queues longer, but more reliable. If this fixes the problem, then you have to make a choice to either settle for a lower number of concurrent jobs on those nodes, or bump up the memory available to them —whether that's the controller (formerly master) or the agents (formerly slaves).